# Defining a Function, := versus =

Tags: core-language

Consider:

```
crossRatio[z_, q_, r_, s_] := (z - q) (r - s)/((z - s) (r - q));
points1 = {-1, 1, (-1 + Sqrt[2]) I};
points2 = {I, -I, 1};
ff[z_] := 
 w /. Solve[
     crossRatio[z, Sequence @@ points1] == 
      crossRatio[w, Sequence @@ points2], w][[1]] // Simplify
```

Now

```
ff[(-1 + Sqrt[2]) I]
```

gives me a sequence of errors:

> Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0 encountered. >>
>   Solve::infc: The system ComplexInfinity==((1/2-I/2) (-I+w))/(-1+w) contains an infinite object ComplexInfinity. >>
>   ReplaceAll::reps: {ComplexInfinity==((1/2-I/2) (-I+w))/(-1+w)} is neither a list of replacement rules nor a valid dispatch table, and so cannot be used for replacing. >>

However, if I leave out the semicolon:

```
ff[z_] = w /. 
   Solve[crossRatio[z, Sequence @@ points1] == 
      crossRatio[w, Sequence @@ points2], w][[1]] // Simplify
```

Then it works.

```
In[262]:= ff[(-1 + Sqrt[2]) I]

Out[262]= (I Sqrt[2] (Sqrt[2]-1)-I (Sqrt[2]-2))/(I Sqrt[2]+I (Sqrt[2]-2) (Sqrt[2]-1))

In[263]:= Simplify[%]

Out[263]= 1
```

How come? What's the difference between f[z_]:= and f[z_]= ?

Comment: Please read this http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/18487 ... and all the other answers in that question, if possible

Comment: Pardon my lack of enthusiasm, but this question seems inappropriate for the site due to being too basic. It is [answered](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Set.html) in the [introductory](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SetDelayed.html) [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/tutorial/ImmediateAndDelayedDefinitions.html).